# Could address written on bank account be used for UK standard visitor visa?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, paperwork, applications

I am an Indian citizen applying for a UK visitor visa. I need to show proof for my current address.

I have a bank account in which my current address is mentioned, I also have a rental agreement but it mentions names of other co-tenants as we are all living in the property.

Which proof should I use for current address ?

Comment: Why not the rental agreement? House and apartment sharing is quite common in the UK, and having co-tenants does not change the fact that is where you live.

Comment: Its pretty common in India too, I was just concerned that because Rental agreement includes details of other people, it might create some confusion in mind of VFS officers.

Comment: What confusion?  Why would they care?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be better to include your rental agreement. Your bank statement address doesn’t prove that you actually live there, it only proves that it is the postal address held by your bank. Your rental agreement, on the other hand, is much stronger evidence of both your address and a tie to your country of residence. Having co-tenants is very common and nothing to be concerned about.

Comment: The fact that he has the statement suggests he at least has access to that address, no? I don’t know what visa requirements are, but for everything official in the U.K., bank statements are certainly valid proof of address.

Comment: Traveller is right. The bank statement is probably adequate, but the rental agreement is much stronger.

Comment: I was just filling out my UK VISA form, and I was asked to enter all address that I have lived in past 2 years, Do I need proof for all of those addresses ?